# How to convert squares using fillPolygon

Tags: java

I have to transform the squares in this program into "cups" using the fillPolygon method in a new class but can't for the life of me figure this out.  I have to reduce the top width by 5 on each side.  Everything I have found in search shows me how to make a triangle or a more complex shape but nothing like this shape.   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  This is what is should look like after the change.

[Screenshot of 'Cups'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnxGV.jpg)

```
package cs520.hw4.part1;



import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class Cups1 extends JFrame{

int startX, startY, cupWidth, cupHeight;
int baseLength;
int cupSpacing;


public Cups1() 
{

    super("My Squares");  


    startX = 100;
    startY = 300;
    cupWidth = 25;
    cupHeight = 40;
    baseLength = 7;
    cupSpacing = 6;

}


public void paint( Graphics g ) 
{

    super.paint(g);     




    for (int row = 0; row < baseLength; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < (baseLength - row); col++)
        {


            if ((row) % 2 == 0){
                g.setColor(Color.RED);}
            else
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);


            g.fillRect(startX + (row * ((cupWidth + cupSpacing) / 2)) + (col * (cupSpacing + cupWidth)), startY - row*cupHeight, cupWidth, cupHeight);
        }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }




public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Cups1 app = new Cups1();

    app.setSize(550,550);
    app.setVisible(true);

    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}


}
```

Comment: how is the thing going? did you do it? do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating some circles and hiding part of them to achieve what you need

```
void drawCircleByCenter(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius){
         //g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         g.drawOval(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
     }
```

or can you upload a screenshot of what you are trying to draw.

Comment: Added link to screenshot.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Better create a method that draws a big rectangle with color (red/blue) as arguement, and inside draw a big rectangle then a small rectangle on top of it with the background color. Then in main method create the logic for calling the big figure.